# How to install every 32 bit library on 64 bit Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, 32-bit

I bought a new laptop this Christmas and installed Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit edition on it. I downloaded Steam and bought Trine 2, but I can't get it to work. I installed ia32-libs, but still nothing. Is there a chance to install every 32 bit libraries on my laptop?

Comment: Every 32 bit library? You actually mean, every? Or all 32 bit versions of everything you already have?

Comment: @NitRo 1) Give us your laptop name/spec. 2) What do you mean 'I can't get it to work'? Where there error messages, strange behaviour? Your post doesn't tell us much.

Comment: Dell Inspiron 5520 i5-3210M, 2,5GHz, 4GB DDR3 RAM, AMD Radeon HD 7670m graphics with 1GB memory. I'm having the same problem as this user: http://youtu.be/dBBIF2wzAb0?t=7m45s the only difference is that on my laptop the black screen is shown only for a second and then goes back to steam.

Comment: go to the location of the steam_latest.deb, 'sudo dpkg -i steam_latest.deb' that will fail, now do 'sudo apt-get -f install' tada, there is steam.

Comment: do you reckon it worked and he got so hooked he hasn't stopped playing to say "thank you"? :-)